# How to limit the GPU memory usage in theano for a particular process?

Tags: python, gpu, theano, flags

I have a theano code which would use around 500MB in my local machine.
But when I run the same code in the server it is occupying the entire GPU Memory which is 12GB.

Is a way to limit the GPU memory usage by setting the flag???

I found a reference to do the same in tensorflow.
But in theano I didn't find any.

Comment: visit http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/faq.html

Comment: There's a flag [`lib.cnmem`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html), which controls the starting memory pool size if you set it to an integer greater than 1. Does including that in the `THEANO_FLAGS` environment variable make any difference?

Comment: Oh thanks it worked out, I set to 0.4 and now it uses only 40% of memory